# Convolution between the derivative Dirac delta function and other function

Tags: dirac-delta

I'm having trouble with the following convolution:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta'(a-t) g(t) dt \textrm{.}
\end{equation}

I know that (I prove this)
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta'(t) g(t) dt \textrm{.}=-g'(0),
\end{equation}

but I can not calculate the other. Can someone tell me how to solve this:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta'(a-t) g(t) dt \textrm{.}
\end{equation}

Comment: So... did you try to use $t'=a-t$?

Comment: Yes, but this not work or I can't see this solution

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = a-t$, so that $ds=-dt$.  Then
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(a-t)g(t)\,dt
   =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(s)g(a-s)\,ds
$$
If we set $\tilde g(s) = g(a-s)$, then according your your previous result, the integral above is $-\tilde g'(0)$.  What is that in terms of the original $g$?

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I see the folowing property:

Comment: Do you forgot the signal "-" in "-dt"?

Answer (score 1):

this result you showed me agree with this??:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta'(a-t) g(t) dt = g'(a) \textrm{.}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{eq:6}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta'(t-a) g(t) dt = -g'(a) \textrm{.}
\end{equation}
See the equatios (19) and (20) in:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html